# Is it possible to implement Both SCD1 and SCD2 in a Table -SSIS

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2012, ssis-2012

I have a `table` where some columns needs to be updated when the data changes & for some columns the history data needs to be preserved. So, Is it possible to have Both `Type 1 Scd` and `Type 2 Scd` in a  table?

Comment: Can you please add package  screen shot and table structure

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Loading Hybrid Dimension Table with SCD1 and SCD2 attributes + SSIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2661574/loading-hybrid-dimension-table-with-scd1-and-scd2-attributes-ssis)

Comment: I strongly recommend using the TSQL statement `MERGE INTO` in `Execute SQL Task`, that is almost the full substitute of SCD